How to match existing crown molding?
I have some crown molding in my living room that looks like may consist of at least 2 different pieces. I'm trying to match it in other rooms and along another wall that connects to it.
Any tips on what the names of each piece are and best way to find a match. My guess is these are some pieces from a big box store like lowes. RELIABILT brand looks kind of similar just eyeballing the pictures online.


Looks like a standard colonial crown with either a lattice or similar material mounted below the crown by a few inches with the drywall painted all the same so it looks like one detail, although it is 2 separate pieces
